# Ubuntu bash - unexpected end of file error

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to learn a bit about bash-commands -- more specifically about backup-scripts.
Unfortunately, I get a syntax error on the last line. I have no idea what I've done wrong and would appreciate any feedback on this matter.

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f $"/archive/backup-20110111.tar.gz" ]; then
    echo "File already exists"
else
    sudo cp /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup-20110111.tar.gz
            /home/plepple/Documents/backup/archive/backup-20110111.tar.gz
    rm /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup-20110111.tar.gz
fi

if [ -f $"/archive/backup-20110112.tar.gz" ]; then
    echo "File already exists"
else
    sudo cp /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup-20110112.tar.gz
            /home/plepple/Documents/backup/archive/backup-20110112.tar.gz
    rm /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup-20110112.tar.gz
fi

curdate='date +%Y%m%d'
mv /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup.tar.gz
   /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup-$curdate.tar.gz
```

I tried to execute it (through bash) with:

```
bash backupscript.sh
```

All the files and directories exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mv /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup.tar.gz
   /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup-$datum.tar.gz
```

should be

```
mv /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup.tar.gz \
   /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup-$datum.tar.gz
```

The same goes for

```
sudo cp /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup-20110111.tar.gz \
            /home/plepple/Documents/backup/archive/backup-20110111.tar.gz
```

and

```
sudo cp /home/plepple/Documents/backup/backup-20110112.tar.gz \
            /home/plepple/Documents/backup/archive/backup-20110112.tar.gz
```

Comment: Newline escapes are missing in the whole script. Perhaps this is only a pasting problem :)

Comment: That seems to be the problem, just checked it in bash

Comment: It seemed to have worked, but I get another error: "target '%Y%m%d' is not a directory." Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, but I don't want to have another directory with that name. I want to change a file name to also have the current date in it. So from: backup.tar.gz to backup-20120119.tar.gz

Comment: `curdate='date +%Y%m%d'` should actually be `curdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)`

Comment: @MichaelKaesy: The problem is that your `date` command is surrounded by single quotes (instead of the backticks you probably intended). That's one of the reasons why `$(date ...)` is preferred (readability). See also [BashFAQ/082](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you so much! I'll have to read up on the functions and the syntax, but again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Where are the `fi`s to end the `if` blocks?

Comment: Hey! I just edited the code, really sorry about that. I assume there only needs to be "fi" after "else", not after the "if" too? :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the problem, just a misc bash syntax correction: in bash, the construct `$"somestring"` invokes localization.  From the bash manpage:

```
A  double-quoted  string  preceded  by a dollar sign ($) will cause the
string to be translated according to the current locale.  If  the  cur-
rent  locale  is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored.  If the string
is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.
```

That doesn't appear to be relevant to the filepaths in your `if` tests, so you should probably leave the `$` off.  Actually, since the filepaths don't have any funny characters in them, you don't even need the quotes around them (although overuse of double-quotes is much better than underuse).